# How to stop Cypress saving login details

Tags: cypress

I am using cypress to automate the testing of a website

After I login with some credentials, Cypress saves them so next time I do cy.visit('/') instead of me being able to enter a second set of credentials, Cypress automatically logs me in using the first set. Is there a way i can stop cypress doing this?

Has anyone else ran into this issue?

I have tried enabling testIsolation and also adding Cypress.session.clearAllSavedSessions() to my beforeEach but neither do the job.

Comment: are you talking about that it uses the same browser session/state/cookies?

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case

Comment: What does your Cypress code look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should only occur if you have ***explicitly*** turned off test isolation. See [Documentation for test isolation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation).

The test code with the ***second credentials*** should be in a ***second test***. Between the two tests, Cypress will clean up all the login artifacts for you (provided you have test isolation turned on).

For example, see this test for `saucedemo.com`. (Make sure you have `chromeWebSecurity: false` set in `cypress.config.js` to run this example)

#### With testIsolation set to false

```js
describe('login example saucedemo', {testIsolation:false}, () => {

  it('inventory page is blocked, requires a login', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html', {failOnStatusCode: false})
    cy.get('h3')
      .should('have.text', "Epic sadface: You can only access '/inventory.html' when you are logged in.")

    cy.get("#user-name").type("standard_user");
    cy.get("#password").type("secret_sauce");
    cy.get("#login-button").click();

    cy.contains('.app_logo', 'Swag Labs').should('be.visible')
  });
  
  it('visits the inventory page using prior test login', () => {

    // In this test, the login credentials persist
    // and we go straight to the inventory page

    cy.visit('https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html', {failOnStatusCode: false})
    cy.contains('.app_logo', 'Swag Labs').should('be.visible')
  })
})
```

[image]

#### With testIsolation set to true

```js
describe('login example saucedemo', {testIsolation:true}, () => {

  it('inventory page is blocked, requires a login', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html', {failOnStatusCode: false})
    cy.get('h3')
      .should('have.text', "Epic sadface: You can only access '/inventory.html' when you are logged in.")

    cy.get("#user-name").type("standard_user");
    cy.get("#password").type("secret_sauce");
    cy.get("#login-button").click();

    cy.contains('.app_logo', 'Swag Labs').should('be.visible')
  });
  
  it('prior test login has been cleared, must login again', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html', {failOnStatusCode: false})
    cy.get('h3')
      .should('have.text', "Epic sadface: You can only access '/inventory.html' when you are logged in.")

    cy.get("#user-name").type("visual_user");        // using a different user
    cy.get("#password").type("secret_sauce");
    cy.get("#login-button").click();

    cy.contains('.app_logo', 'Swag Labs').should('be.visible')
  })
})
```

[image]